# Is someone able to hack my Facebook account knowing my Dynamic IP, PPPoE and mask?

Tags: ip, router

I was using Facebook today and, after replying politely to someone about how stupid his comment on something was, Mr. John Doe, who I never met before, sent me this message:

> *You wanna get hacked, huh? In less than 3 minutes I was able to get your dynamic IP, PPPoE and mask (your machine is pretty vulnerable). 
>   But stay calm and call your computer technician. Best wishes*

Can he hack my Facebook account just with that? I think he was bluffing or something.

If it helps, I am using a regular DSL wireless router, a desktop computer with a USB Wi-Fi receiver and the machine has Windows 7. By the way, I changed the router administration password as soon as I got the wireless router, months before this happened.

Comment: Are you worried about your Facebook account getting hacked or your computer? You seem to combine those worries.

Comment: Actually, I am not worried. I just thought it was pretty strange he would say that because, although I am only a programmer, I thought it would be hard to do that just with those info he said he's got. It looks like he needs something else, idk. Anyway, hacking my facebook would be much easier, I suppose.

Comment: It's probably better not to escalate but if he continues to bother you, report him to Facebook. I'm sure they would be unhappy with his behavior.

Comment: This is a bit like saying I know the address of your bank, I could easily break into the vault and steal your money.

Comment: @Prinsig Or more like I know your home address, I could access your bank account. (Since the IP of a private computer has nothing to do with anyones Facebook account)

Comment: Anyone who boasts about knowing your "mask", which has only 32 possibilities in IPv4 and is set to the same value in almost all home NATs, probably has no knowledge how IP networks work, let alone hacking your computer. Getting your IP and PPPoE account are even more far fetched unless the guy is in a privileged position in the government.

Comment: He probably used your subnet mask to flip-flop your gateway packets via The Mainframe. Send your byte stream though The Unix Socket and filter your protocols; you'll be fine.

Comment: `...to get your ..., PPPoE...` Now that would be a neat trick (whatever it's supposed to mean) to do in "3 minutes". I'd be radically underwhelmed over such a comment.

Comment: Reboot your router, TaDa.. you've got a new public IP..

Comment: This brings me back to that scene in White House Down when that guy says "It may be har for you but for me its as easy as 1,2,3.." Haha, So, the answer is **NO** as long as John Doe is not a movie character.

Comment: This is copypasta. You're not even the first person to post it in a question here.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your IP is a public address and has nothing to do with your Facebook account. Just knowing it does not help someone to 'hack' you. In the same way, knowing your IP does not increase your threat of your computer being hacked.

He's blustering.

Comment: Be fair. The antagonist might merely be clueless.

Comment: Do note that he didn't actually tell you your IP address. That leaves me in serious doubt if he actually got it. If he had your IP he could have looked up the city you were in. I suspect that would have had much greater freak-out potential.

Comment: @NeilSmithline It's Facebook - the OP advertises what city he is from ....

Comment: There's a setting to enable/disable that. But your point that it would be less dramatic if it is public is well taken.

Comment: "...knowing your IP doesn't increase the threat of being hacked" - Huh? It does, and by a significant margin. Port scan with a subsequent attack on open ports looking for unfixed- or zero-day vulnerabilities, is a quite real threat. Of course, if it is just some-guy-nobody-really-cares-about (i.e. not somebody with Really Important Secrets) computer, nobody is going to spend a zero-day on it, so the zero-day attack isn't likely, but brushing it away as impossible is IMHO too much. That being said, I concur with Neil Smithline.

Comment: `Just knowing it does not help someone to 'hack' you.` I don't agree with this statement. IP address is one of the first thing that an attacker needs to hack the machine. Ofcourse it helps the attacker. It is a different matter if the IP is dynamic or behind a NAT... Yes, there is a possibility that someone can hack your FB with your IP. Consider a scenario that you are visiting FB via unsecure connection using free WiFi provided by some cafe. The guy sitting next to your table might already compromised your FB!

Comment: @No-BugsHare I didn't say it was 'impossible' - I said that the threat is not increased. If the target is susceptible to an attack that requires only the IP, then it is susceptible to the 100's of port scans they are exposed to every hour. One more scan does not increase the threat.

Comment: @pss see above. Also, your WiFi/FB scenario is confused. The person sitting next to you in the cafe would see the public IP, which would direct them to themselves (and everyone else in the cafe). The person sitting next to you would use very different techniques that would take advantage of the fact that you share the local network.

Comment: " If the target is susceptible to an attack that requires only the IP, then it is susceptible to the 100's of port scans they are exposed to every hour. One more scan does not increase the threat" - Wrong. Once again: an attack vector of "get your IP - spend $30K to buy zero-day attack - attack you using IP+zero-day" is not exactly feasible without your IP, and does increase threat level significantly (if not dramatically). Your comment is based on the premise of "all attacks are already known to everybody", which is outright wrong.

Comment: @No-BugsHare your logic is faulty - as long as some attacks are known to some, and for sale, then the risk continues to be uniform. The only unbalancing of the risk would occur if that person had unique knowledge of a vulnerability. Given the scenario, this seems unlikely at best. Please adjust your tone.

Comment: "as long as some attacks are known to some, and for sale, then the risk continues to be uniform" - wrong again. As zero-days are mostly one-time sales, this logic doesn't fly. And I even didn't start to analyze scenarios when known attacks cause much more damage because of attacker having knowledge about target person. Generic attacks may or may not cause severe damage (quite a few attacks are just using target as spammer server, which is not too bad); targeted attacks (facilitated by known IP) not just "can", they *tend* to be much more devastating (e.g. blackmail). Another risk increase.

Comment: The same thing from a different point of view: exposing your IP to a *motivated* attacker is much worse than all the other (existing, but not motivated to break exactly you) attackers out there. This difference is very similar to the difference between spearphishing and phishing, and spearphishing is well-known (see e.g. RSA'2011) (a) to penetrate much deeper and (b) to cause much more damage than simple phishing. Spearphishing requires to know "at least something" about the target to mount, and while usually it is e-mail which is used for spearphishing, IP can also be used.

Comment: @NeilSmithline `If he had your IP he could have looked up the city you were in.` Maybe. In the past 10 years, my public IP address has rarely even been close to the town I'm near. Tonight it's as close as I ever recall, right at 300 miles off the mark. It's usually 1500+mi. off.

Comment: @schroeder The cafe thing will definitely work if the guy is also on the same network as the victim. I forgot to mention this in my comment. Also what if the attacker gets access to the default gateway with default credentials. There are many possibilities. What if the attacker creates a rouge access point with same SSID and sniff the unencrypted traffic. This method is the easiest one because most of the people are crazy for free Internet. :)

Answer (score 20):

Your IP isn't public by default (every website you visit knows it, but that's it) and some random guy on Facebook *shouldn't* be able to get it. To get it he would need to trick you into visiting a website he controls or use other tricks (for example I think Skype leaked your IP for a while, don't know if they fixed it or he could possibly get it from an e-mail you sent, there are lots of tricks but I can't think of an easy one to do on Facebook itself).

Your IP isn't directly useful for hacking your Facebook account, but it's very useful if someone intends to hack your computer (and if your computer is hacked then the hacker knows all your passwords, including your Facebook passwords).

Most likely it's a bluff. If your router and computer are up to date (software-wise) even if someones knows your IP (which is dynamic, i.e. it can change at any moment though it doesn't need to and becomes useless to an attacker once it changes. You could power-cycle your router and would likely get a new one) and sensibly configured (for example changed the router password after receiving it, good) then it would likely be very expensive (time and money) to hack you.

I wouldn't spend a second thought on it (besides laughing about it) unless you know you insulted a serious hacker/computer scientist.

Comment: One more way to get IP is from e-mail headers (even webmail services tend to include your IP into headers, to help fighting spammers).

Comment: Thanks for that tip, I never would have thought that my IP would be included when using webmail services.

Comment: Not all ISPs cycle through IPs like you mention. I have had the same IP for months and cycling the modem doesn't change it.

Comment: True, it's essentially random in the sense that the ISP can do whatever they want (unless you pay them for a static IP). Clarified the answer.

Comment: Another way to get an IP address is to embed an image somewhere, such as in a forum signature, or in a pm, or in an email. Although I think gmail will copy the image to their own servers so the email method won't work if the person you are targeting uses gmail.

Comment: That's what I meant with "trick you into visiting a website he controls". I don't know if I should rephrase this. I can't account for every possibility, I wanted to stay general.